# Non-Prefixed messages on Disxord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message,channel):
    if message.content.startswith("sa"):
        await channel.send(message.channel, "as")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

This code should say `as` when I say `sa`. It detects the word but it doesn't respond. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\discordmasterbot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'
```

I'm thinking It might be an outdated code so I tried to change it as new as possible but I'm getting that error.

```
 @client.event
 async def on_message(message):
     if message.content.startswith('sa'):
         await message.channel.send('as')
     await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: If I developed the library I would either pass in the channel through message or channel, but not both...so try removing channel in the list of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you had got the code from but an old project I did in 2018 uses this function signature:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("sa"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "as")
```

However, since then, it looks like [discord.py has migrated to a new version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#). Here is the new way to do it from the [quickstart documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

So what you want is probably the last few parts:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('sa'):
        await message.channel.send('as')
```

**EDIT**

It looks like your code also got the `process_commands` part wrong. `process_commands` is a method of `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, not `client`. So it should be `bot.process_commands(message)`.

Comment: It works bot it doesn't detect any other commands after I put it. Not even m!help

Comment: I have omitted the `await client.process_commands(message)` just to show you a minimal example. Try adding that at the bottom

Comment: It should still be `await client.process_commands(message)` if OP uses `client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`

Comment: no i am not using that. can you guys tell me where to out the edit